# Muting sound problems

Tags: java, audio

I got some problem on muting a sound or music
well i did made the sound muted but the sound that already running or music loop
is not muted!

Code:

```
public static void playSound(String path, int loop) {
    try {
        if (isSoundEnabled) {
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResource(path));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(loop);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        isSoundEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

This prevent a new sound from being played but wont stop the old sound that already played or still looped.

Comment: You question doesn't make sense to me, please clarify it..!!

Comment: it means if i mute the sound it wont add a new sound playing but the old sound that already playing or looping wont stop

Comment: How you are stopping the old sound? The thing, that I am seeing in your program is that, it is only taking the sound from the source and playing it? I didn't seeing any stopping method. Are you pressing some kind of button? If you are, can I see your action perform method of that button

Comment: I mute the sound with keyboard F8 button every time the button pressed
it switched to isSoundEnabled to true or to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see any action performed method, So I am explaining it from the beginning.

1. check this link out,
   [Get sound on button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570537/java-no-sound-played-for-button)

Once, you have the sound playing, now you need to **Stop the Sound** by adding method of stopping in to the same action listener that is playing sound, or you can create another button to stop the currently playing sound.

1. check this link out out [Stop music clip in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833553/how-to-stop-a-music-clip-in-java?rq=1)
2. check this one also [Another method to stop the sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833553/how-to-stop-a-music-clip-in-java?rq=1)

If you have any other question about all the links, feel free to ask me..!!